# Element-wise mutiplication .* of vectors gives matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication, elementwise-operations

Given two vectors

```
a = 1:3;
b = 2:4;
```

it's well known that the element-wise mutiplication `a.*b` produces

```
[ 2  6  12 ]
```

Calling that result `c`, we have `c(i) = a(i)*b(i)`

But I don't understand how `a.*b'`, `b'.*a` and `b'*a` all produce

```
[ 2     4     6
  3     6     9
  4     8    12 ]
```

For the matrix multiplication `b'*a`, we know `c(i,j) = b(i)*a(j)`. 

But why do the other two also produce the same result?

Comment: [Implicit expansion](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to implicit expansion ([introduced in 2016b](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/)) it's essentially the same as using `bsxfun`. 

**But what does that *mean*?**

Setup:

```
a = 1:3;
b = 2:4;
```

- All MATLAB versions:

  ```
  c = a.*b; 
  % c = [2 6 12], element-wise multiplication c(j) = a(j)*b(j)

  c = b'*a;  
  % c = [2 4 5; 3 6 9; 4 8 12]
  % standard matrix multiplication of vectors
  % c(i,j) = a(i) + b(j)

  c = bsxfun(@times, b', a)
  % c = [2 4 5; 3 6 9; 4 8 12]
  % bsxfun applies the function (in this case @times) to b' and a
  ```

  By definition, `bsxfun` "applies the element-by-element binary operation specified by the function handle fun to arrays A and B, **with singleton expansion enabled**". This means that singleton dimensions (dimensions whose size is 1) are expanded row-wise/column-wise to match the size of the other argument supplied to `bsxfun`.

  So, `bsxfun(@times, b', a)` is equivalent to

  ```
   % b' in singleton in the 2nd dimension, a is singleton in the 1st dimension
   % Use repmat to perform the expansion to the correct size
   repmat(b', 1, size(a,2)) .* repmat(a, size(b',1), 1)
   % Equivalent to...
   repmat(b', 1, 3) .* repmat(a, 3, 1)
   % Equivalent to...
   [2 2 2; 3 3 3; 4 4 4] .* [1 2 3; 1 2 3; 1 2 3]   
   % = [2 4 5; 3 6 9; 4 8 12] the same as b'*a
  ```
- Before R2016b

  ```
  c = a.*b'; % Error: Matrix dimensions must agree.
  c = b'.*a; % Error: Matrix dimensions must agree.
  ```
- Since R2016b

  Newer MATLAB versions use implicit expansion, which basically means that a `bsxfun` equivalent is called 'under the hood' if necessary for a valid operation.

  ```
  c = a.*b'; % [2 4 5; 3 6 9; 4 8 12] the same as bsxfun(@times, a, b')
  c = b'.*a; % [2 4 5; 3 6 9; 4 8 12] the same as bsxfun(@times, b', a)
  % These two are equivalent also because order of operations is irrelevant
  % We can see this by thinking about the expansion discussed above
  ```

---

As you've noticed, this can be confusing if you don't keep track of your vector orientations! If you ever want to get a 1D output (without expansion), then you can ensure your inputs are 1D *column vectors* by using the colon operator like so

```
c = a(:).*b(:); % c = [2; 6; 12] always a column vector
```

Answer (score 1):

The examples you listed are all element-wise multiplication.

`a.*b'` will give error in earlier matlab, while it performs

```
bsxfun(@times, a, b')
```

in Matlab since R2016b. This should explain the identical result for `a.*b'`, `b'.*a` and `b'*a`.

`a * b'` will be matrix multiplication (inner dimension match).

Comment: I guess you mean `R2016b`. I'm still not clear why results of `a.*b'` and `b'.*a` are not transposition of each other.